# "Leftparen before dot" nightmare in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, adobe

Trying to create a custom pod for Adobe Connect, using some found source code.

Need to add a few lines in about sync connectors, and then I get the error that there should be a "leftparen before dot".

```
import com.adobe.sync.components.SyncConnector;
import com.adobe.sync.events.SyncSwfEvent;

//Define you SyncConnector
var connector:SyncConnector;

//Add an init function so the Flex wrapper can pass the connector
function init(c:SyncConnector):void
{
    connector = c;

}   

/* Drag and Drop
Makes the specified symbol instance moveable with drag and drop.
*/

Expo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag);

function fl_ClickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Expo.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Expo.stopDrag();
}

function SyncConnector.dispatchSyncMessage(event:MouseEvent)
function SyncConnector.syncMessageReceived(event:MouseEvent)
```

Comment: Function names are not allowed to have dots in them. I.e. your two last lines.

Comment: Thank you - what should it look like? every time I replace it, it appears with a new error?

Comment: Remove them -- those declarations are syntax errors.

Comment: I need to have the sync connector in somewhere to send a message that the mouse has clicked and dragged a movie clip, then another to receive the message that that has happened. I'm pretty stuck now!